# Using R to interpret a symbolic formula for outside use

Tags: r, parsing, formula

In R, the formula object is symbolic and it seems rather hard to parse. However, I need to parse such a formula into an explicit set of labels for use outside of R.

(1)

Letting `f` represent the [model formulae](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) in which a response is not specified, e.g. `~V1 + V2 + V3`, one thing I tried was:

```
t <- terms(f)
attr(t, "term.labels")
```

However, this doesn't get what is exactly explicit if some of the variables in `f` are categorical. For example, let `V1` be a categorical variable with 2 categories, i.e. a boolean, and let `V2` be a double.

Therefore, a model that is specified by `~V1:V2` should have 2 parameters: "intercept" and "xyes:z". Meanwhile, a model that is specified by `~V1:V2 - 1` should have parameters "xno:z" and "xyes:z". However, without a way of telling the function `terms()` which variables are categorical (and how many categories) is has no way of being able to interpret these. Instead, it just has `V1:V2` in its "terms.labels" which doesn't mean anything in the context that `V1` is categorical.

(2)

On the other hand, using `model.matrix` is an easy way to get exactly what I want. The problem is that it requires a `data` argument, which is bad for me because I only want an explicit interpretation of the symbolic formula for use outside of R. This method of getting that will waste a lot time (comparatively) because R has to read the data from an outside source when all it really needs to know for the formula is which variables are categorical (and how many categories) and which variables are doubles.

Is there any way to use 'model.matrix' with only specifying the types of data, rather than the actual data? If not, what else is a viable solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is only in the context of having data that it can be determined whether a given variable is a factor or numeric. So you can't do it without the data argument. But all you need is the structure, not the data itself, so you can use a 0-row data frame with the columns of all the right types.

```
f <- ~ V1:V2
V1numeric <- data.frame(V1=numeric(0), V2=numeric(0))
V1factor <- data.frame(V1=factor(c(), levels=c("no","yes")), V2=numeric(0))
```

Looking at the two data.frames:

```
> V1numeric
[1] V1 V2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> str(V1numeric)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: num 
 $ V2: num 
> V1factor
[1] V1 V2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> str(V1factor)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 
 $ V2: num
```

Use `model.matrix` with these

```
> model.matrix(f, data=V1numeric)
     (Intercept) V1:V2
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1
> model.matrix(f, data=V1factor)
     (Intercept) V1no:V2 V1yes:V2
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$V1
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

If you have a real data set, it is easy to get a 0-row data.frame from that which retains the column information. Just subscript it with `FALSE`. You don't need to build the data.frame by hand if you have one with the right properties.

```
> str(mtcars)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
 $ hp  : num  110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
 $ drat: num  3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
 $ wt  : num  2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
 $ qsec: num  16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
 $ vs  : num  0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ am  : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gear: num  4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
 $ carb: num  4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
> str(mtcars[FALSE,])
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num 
 $ cyl : num 
 $ disp: num 
 $ hp  : num 
 $ drat: num 
 $ wt  : num 
 $ qsec: num 
 $ vs  : num 
 $ am  : num 
 $ gear: num 
 $ carb: num
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do have a real data set, but it is large and outside R so reading it is what reduces efficiency. What you have in the first part looks great, but one thing I don't understand is that `model.matrix(f, data=V1Factor)` produces 3 relevant parameters, when it shouldn't have `V1no:V2` as there is an intercept.

Comment: R is known to be reluctant to remove lower order parameters when interactions are present, perhaps that is the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11335923/289572

Comment: @JonClaus I think it should have three parameters: the intercept, the slope of `V2` when `V1` is no, and the slope of `V2` when `V1` is yes (the way it is parametrized here). You could also get 3 parameters with an intercept, a slope of `V2` when `V1` is no, and the change in the slope of `V2` when `V1` changes from no to yes. However you parametrize it, there are 3 parameters.

Comment: Also, you don't need to read the whole data set that is outside of R; just enough of it to get the structure. Or if you know the structure, you can just create that "by hand" and not have to read anything in. Whichever approach is easiest; both work.

Comment: Alright, that shouldn't be too much of a problem to deal with outside of R once I have the explicit labels for parameters. Thanks.